# Scrape time, title and content not from a news list, but from cover and column cover news and sidebar

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, screen-scraping

I have a window with a button that scrapes the news headlines of a site into a listbox, then I have another button that scrapes the news content related to the selected headline and displays them in a textobox

Currently on the page I scrape all the titles, their timetable and their contents, but I would also like to add the title (with the relative content) that is on the cover of the page [(this)](https://ibb.co/X79JVkx), and also all the titles (with the relative contents) that are on the right column of the page [(this)](https://ibb.co/4V4d2G7).

The ease is that the titles on the right column all always have the same unique html name, but the time is not directly visible because you have to open the link to get the time.

I have tried using these, but without success

```
title_cover = " ".join(span.text for span in div.select("title absolute serif"))
title_sidebar = " ".join(span.text for span in div.select("bold"))
time_cover_and_sidebar = div.find('span', attrs={'class': 'upper'}).text
news_cover = f" {time_cover_and_sidebar} {place.upper()}, {title_cover} (TMW)"
news_sidebar = f" {time_cover_and_sidebar} {place.upper()}, {title_sidebar} (TMW)"
results_cover.append( [number, time_cover_and_sidebar, place, title_cover, news, link] )
results_sidebar.append( [number, time_cover_and_sidebar, place, title_sidebar, news, link])
```

The output I would like to get is the same as the one I get with the code already provided (time, place/name team, title), with the difference that I would also like to insert time, titles and content of the cover and sidebar news
[image]

Complete executable code:

```
import tkinter as tk   # PEP8: `import *` is not preferred
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter.scrolledtext import ScrolledText 
import requests
import requests_cache 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

# PEP8: all imports at the beginning

# --- functions ---   # PEP8: all functions directly after imports

def get_data_for(place):
    headers = {
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36'
    }

    results = []

    response = requests.get(f'https://www.tuttomercatoweb.com/{place}/', headers=headers)
    print('url:', response.url)
    print('status:', response.status_code)
    #print('html:', response.text[:1000])

    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')

    news = soup.find_all('div', attrs={"class": "tcc-list-news"})

    for number, each in enumerate(news):
        for div in each.find_all("div"):
            time  = div.find('span', attrs={'class': 'hh serif'}).text
            title = " ".join(span.text for span in div.select("a > span"))
            news = f" {time} {place.upper()}, {title} (TMW)"
            link  = div.find('a')['href']
            results.append( [number, time, place, title, news, link] )

    return results

def all_titles():
    global df

    allnews = []  # local variable

    for place in ['atalanta',  'bologna']:
        print('search:', place)
        results = get_data_for(place)
        print('found:', len(results))
        allnews += results
        text_download.insert('end', f"search: {place}\nfound: {len(results)}\n")

    df = pd.DataFrame(allnews, columns=['number', 'time', 'place', 'title', 'news', 'link'])
    df = df.sort_values(by=['number', 'time', 'place', 'title'], ascending=[True, False, True, True])
    df = df.reset_index()

    listbox_title.delete('0', 'end')

    for index, row in df.iterrows():
        listbox_title.insert('end', row['news'])

def content(event=None):   # `command=` executes without `event`, but `bind` executes with `event` - so it needs default value
    # tuple
    selection = listbox_title.curselection()
    print('selection:', selection)

    if selection:

        item = df.iloc[selection[-1]]
        #print('item:', item)

        url = item['link']
        #print('url:', url)

        headers = {
            'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36'
        }

        # keep page in database `SQLite` 
        # https://github.com/reclosedev/requests-cache
        # https://sqlite.org/index.html
        session = requests_cache.CachedSession('titles')
        response = session.get(url, headers=headers)
        #response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')

        content_download = "\n".join(item.get_text() for item in soup.select("div.text.mbottom"))

        text_download.delete('1.0', 'end') # remove previous content)
        text_download.insert('end', content_download)

# --- main ---

df = None

window = tk.Tk()
window.geometry("800x800")

# ---
# [Tkinter: How to display Listbox with Scrollbar — furas.pl](https://blog.furas.pl/python-tkitner-how-to-display-listbox-with-scrollbar-gb.html)

frame_title = tk.Frame(window)
frame_title.pack(fill='both', expand=True, pady=5, padx=5)

listbox_title = tk.Listbox(frame_title, selectbackground="#960000", selectforeground="white", bg="white")
listbox_title.pack(side='left', fill='both', expand=True)

scrollbar_title = tk.Scrollbar(frame_title)
scrollbar_title.pack(side='left', fill='y')

scrollbar_title['command'] = listbox_title.yview
listbox_title.config(yscrollcommand=scrollbar_title.set)

listbox_title.bind('<Double-Button-1>', content)  # it executes `content(event)`

# ----

text_download = ScrolledText(window, bg="white")
text_download.pack(fill='both', expand=True, pady=0, padx=5)

# ----

buttons_frame = tk.Frame(window)
buttons_frame.pack(fill='x')

button1 = tk.Button(buttons_frame, text="View Titles", command=all_titles)  # don't use `[]` to execute functions
button1.pack(side='left', pady=5, padx=5)

button2 = tk.Button(buttons_frame, text="View Content", command=content)   # don't use `[]` to execute functions
button2.pack(side='left', pady=5, padx=(0,5))

window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

In the future, trim down your posts/question to only include minimal amount of code to answer the question. Tkinter isn't really part of what you want to fix here.

With that being said, I only updated code pertaining to getting those cover and side news. You are correct, you need to go to the link to get the data. You could parse then from the html, or they do provide a nice json format in the `<script>` tags on the site to get that.

```
import tkinter as tk   # PEP8: `import *` is not preferred
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter.scrolledtext import ScrolledText 
import requests
import requests_cache 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import re
import json
from dateutil import parser
import datetime
import locale

# PEP8: all imports at the beginning

# --- functions ---   # PEP8: all functions directly after imports

def get_data_for(place):
    headers = {
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36'
    }

    results = []

    response = requests.get(f'https://www.tuttomercatoweb.com/{place}/', headers=headers)
    print('url:', response.url)
    print('status:', response.status_code)
    #print('html:', response.text[:1000])

    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')

    #Cover
    cover_news = soup.find('div', {'class':'box pp'})
    link = cover_news.find('a', href=True)['href']
    coverNewsResponse = requests.get(link, headers=headers)
    coverSoup = BeautifulSoup(coverNewsResponse.content, 'html.parser')
    jsonStr = str(coverSoup.find('script'))
    jsonStr = re.search('({.*})', jsonStr).group(1)
    jsonData = json.loads(jsonStr)
    
    timePublished = parser.parse(jsonData['datePublished']).strftime("%H:%M")
    datePublished = parser.parse(jsonData['datePublished']).strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
    title = jsonData['headline']
    news = f" {timePublished} {place.upper()}, {title} (TMW)"
    results.append( [datePublished, timePublished, place, title, news, link] )

    # Side panel
    side_news = soup.find_all('div', {'class':'box small'})
    for each in side_news:
        link = each.find('a', href=True)['href']
        sideNewsResponse = requests.get(link, headers=headers)
        sideSoup = BeautifulSoup(sideNewsResponse.content, 'html.parser')
        jsonStr = str(sideSoup.find('script'))
        jsonStr = re.search('({.*})', jsonStr).group(1)
        jsonData = json.loads(jsonStr)
        
        timePublished = parser.parse(jsonData['datePublished']).strftime("%H:%M")
        datePublished = parser.parse(jsonData['datePublished']).strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
        title = jsonData['headline']
        news = f" {timePublished} {place.upper()}, {title} (TMW)"
        results.append( [datePublished, timePublished, place, title, news, link] )
        
        

    news = soup.find_all('div', attrs={"class": "tcc-list-news"})

    for each in news:
        for div in each.find_all("div"):
            timePublished  = div.find('span', attrs={'class': 'hh serif'}).text
            datePublished = div.find_previous('div', {'class':'tcc-border upper date'})
            
            if datePublished:
                if datePublished.text in ['Ieri']:
                    yesterday = datetime.datetime.today() - datetime.timedelta(days = 1)
                    datePublished = yesterday.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
                else:
                    locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'it')
                    currentYear = datetime.datetime.today().strftime("%Y")
                    dateStr = datePublished.text
                    dateStr = datetime.datetime.strptime(dateStr + ' ' + currentYear, '%A %d %B %Y')
                    datePublished = dateStr.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
            else:
                datePublished = datetime.datetime.today().strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
            
            title = " ".join(span.text for span in div.select("a > span"))
            news = f" {timePublished} {place.upper()}, {title} (TMW)"
            link  = div.find('a')['href']
            results.append( [datePublished, timePublished, place, title, news, link] )

    return results

def all_titles():
    global df

    allnews = []  # local variable

    for place in ['atalanta',  'bologna']:
        print('search:', place)
        try:
            results = get_data_for(place)
            print('found:', len(results))
            allnews += results
            text_download.insert('end', f"search: {place}\nfound: {len(results)}\n")
        except Exception as e:
            print(f'Error with {place}')
            continue
            

    df = pd.DataFrame(allnews, columns=['date', 'time', 'place', 'title', 'news', 'link'])
    df = df.sort_values(by=['date', 'time', 'place', 'title'], ascending=[False, False, True, True])
    df = df.drop_duplicates(subset=['date', 'time', 'place', 'title'])
    df = df.reset_index(drop=True)

    listbox_title.delete('0', 'end')

    for index, row in df.iterrows():
        listbox_title.insert('end', row['news'])

def content(event=None):   # `command=` executes without `event`, but `bind` executes with `event` - so it needs default value
    # tuple
    selection = listbox_title.curselection()
    print('selection:', selection)

    if selection:

        item = df.iloc[selection[-1]]
        #print('item:', item)

        url = item['link']
        #print('url:', url)

        headers = {
            'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36'
        }

        # keep page in database `SQLite` 
        # https://github.com/reclosedev/requests-cache
        # https://sqlite.org/index.html
        session = requests_cache.CachedSession('titles')
        response = session.get(url, headers=headers)
        #response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')

        content_download = "\n".join(item.get_text() for item in soup.select("div.text.mbottom"))

        text_download.delete('1.0', 'end') # remove previous content)
        text_download.insert('end', content_download)

# --- main ---

df = None

window = tk.Tk()
window.geometry("800x800")

# ---
# [Tkinter: How to display Listbox with Scrollbar — furas.pl](https://blog.furas.pl/python-tkitner-how-to-display-listbox-with-scrollbar-gb.html)

frame_title = tk.Frame(window)
frame_title.pack(fill='both', expand=True, pady=5, padx=5)

listbox_title = tk.Listbox(frame_title, selectbackground="#960000", selectforeground="white", bg="white")
listbox_title.pack(side='left', fill='both', expand=True)

scrollbar_title = tk.Scrollbar(frame_title)
scrollbar_title.pack(side='left', fill='y')

scrollbar_title['command'] = listbox_title.yview
listbox_title.config(yscrollcommand=scrollbar_title.set)

listbox_title.bind('<Double-Button-1>', content)  # it executes `content(event)`

# ----

text_download = ScrolledText(window, bg="white")
text_download.pack(fill='both', expand=True, pady=0, padx=5)

# ----

buttons_frame = tk.Frame(window)
buttons_frame.pack(fill='x')

button1 = tk.Button(buttons_frame, text="View Titles", command=all_titles)  # don't use `[]` to execute functions
button1.pack(side='left', pady=5, padx=5)

button2 = tk.Button(buttons_frame, text="View Content", command=content)   # don't use `[]` to execute functions
button2.pack(side='left', pady=5, padx=(0,5))

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Are you sure you need to use json? I am having difficulty merging your code with my code. Maybe there is some rows of code of yours in contrast to some rows of my code. I am new to Python. Could you show me how you apply your code to my code? So in full code as a solution to my question. Thank you

Comment: It's just the `get_data_for()` that you need to replace. I;m not sure what the issue is. Replace your  `get_data_for()` with mine

Comment: Are you referring to the whole function def get_data_for? Should I replace the entire function? Anyway to be precise (I don't know if I explained myself well in my main question): does your code add cover news and various sidebar news in addition to the news that my code already scraped?

Comment: Your code seems to work fine, but there is a problem. News headlines are no longer sorted by time. Previously the news headlines were published in time order, now they are not. Now with your code I'm like this https://ibb.co/GHgmW18  Can you fix this please? It is not an additional solution other than the question, but in my code this problem was not happening. Thanks :)

Comment: Yes it adds the cover news and the side bar to what you already scrape. 

If you want it in time order, we’ll fix the sort.

Comment: But my code was already scraping correctly in time order. Replacing your modification no longer scrapes in time order. Can you help me please? Thank you

Comment: Your code scrapes in time order because the website sorts those articles in time order. The headline and side panels are not posted in time order relative to the list of news you are scraping. So are you saying you want them in order of Date and time?

Comment: I've updated the code. It'll now put thing into date and time order. It will also remove duplicate articles (the side panel sometimes have the same article in the news list.

Comment: Thanks for correcting. I'm getting confused applying your code to mine. Can you show me the complete code which also includes my code in the application? (your code applied to my code). Thank you

Comment: @Jas_99, I updated it with the changes to your full code, but I have not tested it. Putting this into your code is a rather basic process, that really a beginner should be able to handle. My advice is if you can't debug your code, or understand what it's doing or the logical process to make these changes, you need to take a step back and learn some basics/fundamentals of python. Jumping right into web scraping, beautifulsoup, pandas, tkinter, etc. is quite a big leap when you don't have the foundations yet.

Comment: Thank you. I tested your code, but there is an error: File "/usr/lib/python3.8/locale.py", line 608, in setlocale
    return _setlocale (category, local)
locale.Error: locale not supported. how to solve?. I know the basics and fundamentals of Python, not all of them, but I am at a fairly advanced basic level (basic). The problem for me was not how to put your code in mine (in fact it's a simple process I know how to do), but knowing what changes you had made considering the length of the code. I understand the logical process quite well, but there was some confusion with your changes.

Comment: Try changing the line from `locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'it')` to `locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, '')`

Comment: On my end, the site will come back in Italian, so parse the date, it needs to understand March/April etc is in Italian. If that doesn’t work, hang tight, we can adjust the headers to get the English, and then don’t need to worry about setting locale.

Comment: These days I am a little busy and have little time. I tried your code quickly, it seems to work fine. Thank you. I have not looked at it very carefully because these days I have little time. Vote and accept the answer. If I find something that is not working correctly, I will rewrite you a comment. Thank you :)

Comment: PART 1. I re-open the question, because I have encountered some problems in the code.
PROBLEM: Only now, after some time, I realize that in "for place" you write 'lazio', so for place in ['lazio'], your code does not work. It does not print news headlines. The html and CSS code in the page is the same, it hasn't been changed. So the site.com/lazio page is the same as when you created the code. I get this jsonStr = re.search ('({. *})', JsonStr) .group (1) AttributeError: object 'NoneType' has no 'group' attribute.

Comment: PART 2.  After a few hours, the code worked again and scraped everything, perhaps the time that the site.com/lazio page updated the contents. dare another look at your code please? The problem in your code has been around for some time, but I'm only realizing it now. Thank you

Comment: the code works fine.

Comment: NEW PART 1 Apparently yes, it works well. I have tested all the individual pages of the clubs concerned, everything is ok. Unfortunately I encountered a problem with the com / lazio page. The script scraped all pages except .com / lazio. The error I received I wrote in the comment above. After 1 or 2 hours your script worked correctly with com / lazio as well. The problem is that when .com / lazio didn't scratch, it blocked the whole script and therefore wouldn't start.

Comment: NEW PART 2: Now for you and me the script works fine, but there are times when a page doesn't work (after 1 or 2 hours it works) and I don't understand why. Can you fix this in your code please? The error is in the comment above: jsonStr = re.search ('({. *})', JsonStr) .group (1) AttributeError: object 'NoneType' has no 'group' attribute. Excuse me and thank you :)

Comment: Just need to add in a try/except block. I added it to the code, so try that now.

Comment: Thank you. I will try your code later which is now late and I go to sleep. From your edit though, I guess that where there is an error with a single page, then the script still continues skipping the error. But my question is: why doesn't scraping a page sometimes work? Then after 1 hour (for example) it works correctly again. Yet the name of the html and css elements you used is the same and it is correct (I think).

Comment: my guess is that the server/website isn't returning a valid response. Could be for a variety of reasons. could be a poor internet connection, could be the website is doing some maintenance, could be the server you're requesting from is blocking it.

Comment: I exclude poor internet connection and exclude maintenance, otherwise the same other similar pages relating to the other teams did not work either. Only .com/lazio did not work, while the other 19 club pages worked correctly at the same time. At this point, the server option remains: why did he have to block ONLY the page.com/lazio? Could there be other reasons or is it a problem / forgetting your code? Thank you

Comment: It will require more debugging and looking in to, and is beyond the scope of the original post. It is also not good practice to accept an answer, then months later unaccept, to then attach additional requirements. My original post addressed your question/issue, and now you raise a very specific issue found in the solution of the general question. Please have a read [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253762/link-for-poor-or-ever-growing-questions-to-better-explain-why-people-stop-answer) and [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19665/the-help-vampire-problem)

Comment: I've accommodated and updated this solution multiple times, and I will no longer be addressing this. If you further questions, you should open up a new post.